# App.config patches/updates

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config

How can I patch a user's App.config properly when performing an upgrade?

Overwriting the old file is problematic as configuration changes are lost, however, if new values are added / old ones are changed, I can't just keep the old one.

Comment: Carefully? Config files are just XML - you can read it at any time and merge whatever way you want... Also I don't think there is existing "merge config" functionality in .Net... Note that if you'd allow user to change settings in separate file (i.e. global vs. per-user) you could have avoided whole problem - consider for future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've used now is just apply machine specific settings to `user.config`. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends how you are processing the upgrade process and how well you have designed and planned in advanced for minor/major version upgrades. There's no real rocket science behind it as one of the comments stated, you are just dealing with xml files. Moreover, there's a well-designed built-in API in the .NET Framework that allows developers to deal with config files...residing in the `System.Configuration` namespace.

Now, I've done this in the past (the old school way...I don't think much has changed) when I was doing desktop development...I had a web service running somewhere with two endpoints that exposed the latest version of the application and another one that exposed a packaged version of the latest application installer, the application installed on the end-user's desktop would call this service every time the user starts the application, if an upgrade was available the application would start a separate process (the updater) that would handle the version migration and installation. This would take care of all settings migration including config file, local storage (if any), etc.

I'm not claiming it is the best solution or anything, but it gives you a lot of flexibility and control over the process and most importantly it works. That's exactly the same process many big software company follow. But, it does require a bit of planning.